# Looking to remap drives from file VBS

Tags: vbscript

I am very new to VBS. I am trying to make a tool that will help with migration of users for a refresh comming up. I need to grab printers and drive mappings from the current user on a machine, export to a file, copy file to new machine and then import that file. (no registry interaction)

The printer section I have already, Its the mapped network drives that are an issue. IBelow is the script for exporting.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Const ForAppending = 8

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
 ("C:\Mapped_Drives.txt", ForAppending, True)


Set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set colDrives = objNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives
For i = 0 to colDrives.Count-1 Step 2
 objtextfile.writeline (colDrives.Item(i) & vbTab & colDrives.Item (i + 1))
Next
objtextfile.close
```

This creates a file that looks like

P:  \server\share

Z:  \server\share

Y:  \server\share

I am trying to find some way to import this information into the new machine for the same user. Any help would be apperciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Does [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/johnbaker/archive/2010/10/11/migrating-mapped-network-printers-and-network-drives-with-the-mdt-2010-update-1.aspx) help?

Answer (score 0):

.OpenTextFile() the exported file ForReading, loop until .AtEndOfStream, .ReadLine() each line, Split() on vbTab, (check for plausibility), feed the two elements of the Split() array to .MapNetworkDrive.